# How to copy an Image to clipboard in Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to take a screen-shot and save the image to a folder and also to clipboard, screen-shot is taken and saved to a folder without any problem but
it fails to save it on to clipboard. Can anyone help, this is what I have so far.

Is this even possible ?

```
    imbtScreenCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            long name = timestamp.getTime();

            //Taking screenshot and saving to folder
            SDKMediaHelper.I.saveScreenShot("/Pictures/" +name+".jpg", path ->
                    handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(0, path)));
                    
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            String COPY_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Pictures/"+name+".png";
            myDir = new File( COPY_PATH);
            myDir.mkdirs();

            file = new File(String.valueOf(myDir));
            if (file.exists()) file.delete();
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "Test", Uri.fromFile(myDir));
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: "it fails to save it on to clipboard" -- how are you determining this? And, if you switch from `Uri.fromFile()` (largely banned since Android 7.0) to `FileProvider`, do you have better luck?

Comment: When I try to paste the image to any document there's nothing there. I've tried using `FileProvider` unfortunately it didn't work.